# counting form fields, before and after dynamically adding them to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a form, and i want to count all the fields before and after the dropdown 'change'
(which adds extra fields to the form). But currently before and after counts are the same, even when i see the added fields on screen. After selecting something again from the dropdown, the previous correct count is shown.

```
let fieldCount = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control').length
document.getElementById('type').addEventListener('change', () =>{
    console.log(fieldCount)
    fieldCount = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control').length
    console.log('new field count: ', fieldCount)
})
```

What to do ?

Comment: You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: Why will the number of `form-control`s change?

Comment: I have different HTML components with different form fields (also different number of them). Selecting 'weight' from the dropdown, adds 'weigth' field, but selecting 'dimensions' adds three fields: 'height', 'width' and 'length'. I'm trying to do a validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to check for changes in the DOM is to use a `MutationObserver`.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

I'll now describe what I did below:

The function `getFormElementCount` just checks for all elements inside the form. I replaced your `document.querySelectorAll('.form-control')` with the `HTMLFormElement` property `elements` and filtered them afterwards to exclude elements like fieldsets or buttons.

If you have full control over your HTML you can safely stay with your querySelector.

`printFormElementCount` is just here for representation, so it does not matter that much.

Afterwards I created the `MutationObserver` and applied the callback `printFormElementCount`, so everytime the `observer` recognizes some changes in the Form the function will run.

```js
const getFormElementCount = (form) => {
  if ("elements" in form !== true) {
    return false;
  }

  // Elements like button or fieldset should not
  // be counted. This can be extended to also
  // disallow elements from specific types
  const excludedTags = ["fieldset", "button"];

  const elements = [...form.elements];
  const filtered = elements.filter(
    (el) => !excludedTags.includes(el.tagName.toLowerCase())
  );

  // Get the final count
  const count = filtered.length;
  return count;
};

const printFormElementCount = () => {
  const countEl = document.querySelector(".elementCount");
  countEl.replaceChildren(getFormElementCount(form));
};

const form = document.querySelector("form");

// Create an observer instance linked to the printFormElementCount
// callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(printFormElementCount);
// Start observing the target node for childList
observer.observe(form, { childList: true });

// Print Form Element Count on load
printFormElementCount();

// Create new Form Element
const newFormEl = document.createElement("input");
newFormEl.type = "text";
newFormEl.name = "some-name";

form.appendChild(newFormEl);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="test" />
</form>
<div class="elementCount"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, great stuff. Didn't know about MutationObserver. I think i can use this. First i'll finish regular validation with "submit", then try adding this MutationObserver stuff.